# Select row when value is in range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Given the two column below how can I select the row 110-118 if my filter is 111? 100-118 is a range thus 111 falls between 100-118

```
Dest_ZIP    Ground
004-005     003
009         005
068-089     002
100-118     001
```

Comment: You should have had two separate Dest_ZIP columns.

Comment: You should store these informations in two separate columns `ZipStart` and `ZipEnd` if it is a range.

Comment: You could always explode the range "100-118" into an array with 2 values ( 100 and 118 ) , than compare the 111 with the 2 values.. if is  >= 100 and <=118, it is in range.

Comment: Sometimes Dest_ZIP column is not a range.

Answer (score 2):

Below is a simple example of how to do this in SQL using a sub query to get the start and end range. This can be expanded on to better handle parsing the string value.

```
Declare @Temp TABLE
(
Dest_Zip varchar(7),
Ground varchar(3)
)

INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES ('004-005','003')
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES ('068-089','002')
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES ('100-118','001')

SELECT A.Dest_Zip, A.Ground FROM
(
select 
Convert(int, SUBSTRING(Dest_Zip,1,3)) StartNum,
Convert(int, SUBSTRING(Dest_Zip,5,3)) EndNum,
*
from @Temp
) AS A

WHERE 111 >= A.StartNum AND 111 <= A.EndNum
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix the data.  Here is a simple way using computed columns (and assuming the "zips" are always 3 characters):

```
alter table t
    add column minzip as (left(dest_zip), 3),
    add column maxzip as (right(dest_zip), 3);
```

Then, you can run the query as:

```
select t.*
from t
where '111' between t.minzip and t.maxzip;
```

You can even create an index on computed columns, which can help performance (although not much in this case).

Comment: The data is coming from UPS.com I can change it but if UPS.com change their data I have do the editing of the data again. I like the data to stay as it is.

Comment: You can add computed columns to the table after you load it from UPS.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to make the checks in php, maybe this sample code can help you:

```
<?php 

$my_string = "111";

$foo = "100-118";  // our range

$bar = explode('-', $foo);  // Get an array .. let's call it $bar
// Print the output, see how the array looks
//print_r($bar);
//echo $bar[0].'<br />';  
//echo $bar[1].'<br />';

if(($bar[0] <= $my_string ) AND ($bar[1] >= $my_string)){ echo 'true';} else { echo 'false';}

?>
```